# How to apply formulas on condition to generate a new column and apply two types of ranking?

Tags: python, pandas

Input:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['abc1',55,98,100],['abc2',56,97,101],['abc3',13,18,55],['abc4',56,79,100]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Bus','Existing_Fare','Petrol_Price','Salary_Hike'])
```

1. I need to apply this formula.

IF Petrol_Price>80: Petrol_Price=80 else:  Petrol_Price given in dataframe

New Price = Existing_Fare+Petrol_Price+2*Salary_Hike

2.Ranking Correct Order.

3. If two scores have same value then give them same rank

Output

```
Bus New_Price   Rank_Order  Rank_duplicates
0   abc1    335  1          2
1   abc2    338  2          1
2   abc3    141  3          3
3   abc4    335  4          2
```

Comment: Is there anything you have tried so far?

Comment: Why is New_Price at index 2 `13` ?  I'm getting `141` with your formula

Comment: Yeah that's correct will edit

Comment: What is `Rank_Order`?

Comment: @sobek just simply give them numbers in incremental order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df.assign(
    Petrol_Price=df.Petrol_Price.clip(0, 80)
).eval(
    'New_Price=Existing_Fare + Petrol_Price + 2 * Salary_Hike'
).assign(
    Rank_Duplicates=lambda d: d.New_Price.rank(method='dense', ascending=False)
)

    Bus  Existing_Fare  Petrol_Price  Salary_Hike  New_Price  Rank_Duplicates
0  abc1             55            80          100        335              2.0
1  abc2             56            80          101        338              1.0
2  abc3             13            18           55        141              3.0
3  abc4             56            79          100        335              2.0
```

Comment: Ranking  the new_price

Comment: Rank_Duplicates

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.  Your `Rank_order` is just `[1, 2, 3, 4]` which looks nothing like a ranking of anything.  Further, I've shown that you can use `rank` with the parameter `method='dense'` to adjust for duplication.  You haven't explained what `Rank_Order` is and you certainly don't help matters with a comment that simply states "Rank_Duplicates"

Comment: I think your `Rank_Duplicates` is reversed, apart from that your post is as good as it gets with the info from the OP.